# Cannot find @Org Custom Layout in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs

I have recently started using `spacemacs`. After sifting through their documentation I found that `spacemacs` ships with a custom layout for `org-mode`. However, I cannot seem to find the layout by following their [documentation](http://spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION#custom-layouts).

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it. I had to enable the `org` layer in the spacemacs dotfile (`.spacemacs`)

```
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(
     ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
     ;; Example of useful layers you may want to use right away.
     ;; Uncomment some layer names and press <SPC f e R> (Vim style) or
     ;; <M-m f e R> (Emacs style) to install them.
     ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
     helm
     auto-completion
     ;; better-defaults
     emacs-lisp
     ;; git
     ;; markdown
     org
     ;; (shell :variables
     ;;        shell-default-height 30
     ;;        shell-default-position 'bottom)
     spell-checking
     syntax-checking
     ;; version-control
     )
```